# Split string - C# - complicated

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

I've the folllowing string and I want to split it:

```
"INSERT INTO test (test, test1, test2, test3) values (@test, @test1, @test2, @test3)";
```

The values that I want to get are the seperated @test @test1 @test2 @test3 So I can do something different with each one

This is what I currenly have so far.

```
string str = "INSERT INTO test (test, test1, test2, test3) values (@test, @test1, @test2, @test3)"
var pattern = @"(?<=@)[^@]*(?=>,)";
foreach (var m in System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(str, pattern))
     {
        Console.WriteLine(m);
     }
```

This returns the whole string:

```
INSERT INTO test (test, test1, test2, test3) values (@test, @test1, @test2, @test3)
```

I hope some of you can help me because it's the last pin for my program to work.

Comment: The point is: how can you determine the boundaries where these values start from and end at? If you plan to use a regex, it should know where to start matching and where to end.

Comment: I can split it at @ and at , and at the @ later but still how do i do that.

Comment: Ok, try `Regex.Matches(str, @"@\w+").Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Value).ToList()`. Although at this point, Kell's answer should work the same. Well, with the exception that the regex only matches word chars after `@`.

Comment: why not use a String.Format? .... or even better SQLParameters?

Comment: Yeah I used kells answer @WiktorStribiżew and it works perfectly Do you know where I can learn to regex like that ?

Comment: Here, on SO. Just follow the regex tag and you will learn a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I'm not fond of regexes but a lot of people are, so I'll give you my answer as a good old string method:

```
var parameters = str.Split('@').Skip(1).Select(var=>"@" + var.Trim(new[] {',',')', ' '}));
```

Comment: And my variation:
`str.Split(' ', '(', ')', ' ').Where(s => s.StartsWith("@"))`
Split takes a params array, so you don't need to bother creating an array

Comment: works perfectly and I even understand why thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Had you try `string pattern = @"@[a-zA-Z0-9]+";`?

Comment: In the first line it returns INSERT INTO test (test, test1, test2, test3) values(

second ,

third ,

4th  ,

5th )

sorry it places everything on same line you need to read it like number of the row with what it returns

Comment: This seems to be working. Check [here](https://regex101.com/r/wE7tJ8/1)

Comment: @krw12572: Yeah, but not with `Regex.Split` (see [*Split List* here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%40%5ba-zA-Z0-9%5d%2b&i=INSERT+INTO+test+(test%2c+test1%2c+test2%2c+test3)+values+(%40test%2c+%40test1%2c+%40test2%2c+%40test3))).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Although the website didn't high light the @test, but I found it gets the `@test` when I browser the `table` tab. Too lazy to test on C#